# How to copy a column from perl script and print it?

Tags: perl, copy

Query:     3   SSESVENECMCWAARDPSGLLSPHTITRRSVTTDDVSLTITHCGVCYADVIWSRNQHGDS 62

I need to copy `SSESVENECMCWAARDPSGLLSPHTITRRSVTTDDVSLTITHCGVCYADVIWSRNQHGDS` and print this. How? Using perl programming of course. thanks

```
>gnl|Liriodendron|b3_c1691

Query: 3   SSESVENECMCWAARDPSGLLSPHTITRRSVTTDDVSLTITHCGVCYADVIWSRNQHGDS 62
Query: 63  KYPLVPGHEIAGIVTKVGPNVQRFKVGDHVGVGTYVNSCRECEYCNEGQEVNCAK-GVFT 121
Query: 122 FNGIDHDGSVTKGGYSSHIVVHERYCYKIPVDYPLESAAPLLCAGITVYAPMMRHNMNQP 181
Query: 182 GKSLGVIGLGGLGHMAVKFGKAFGLSVTVFSTSISKKEEALNLLGAENFVISSDHDQMKA 241
Query: 242 LEKSLDFLVDTASGDHAFDPYMSLLKIAGTYVLVGFPSEIKISPANLNLGMRMLAGSVTG 301
Query: 302 GTKITQQMLDFCAAHKIYPNIEVIPIQKINEALERVVKKDIKYRFVIDIKNSLK 355
```

This is the output I am getting right now. I want to print only column 2 of each row and print like this

```
>gnl|Liriodendron|b3_c1691

SSESVENECMCWAARDPSGLLSPHTITRRSVTTDDVSLTITHCGVCYADVIWSRNQHGDSKYPLVPGHEIAGIVTKVGPNVQRFKVGDHVGVGTYVNSCRECEYCNEGQEVNCAK-GVFTFNGIDHDGSVTKGGYSSHIVVHERYCYKIPVDYPLESAAPLLCAGITVYAPMMRHNMNQPGKSLGVIGLGGLGHMAVKFGKAFGLSVTVFSTSISKKEEALNLLGAENFVISSDHDQMKALEKSLDFLVDTASGDHAFDPYMSLLKIAGTYVLVGFPSEIKISPANLNLGMRMLAGSVTGGTKITQQMLDFCAAHKIYPNIEVIPIQKINEALERVVKKDIKYRFVIDIKNSLK
```

Here is my coding at the moment:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#This line will ask for file name
print "Entry your BLAST file name \n";

#This line will save the file name into $file
my $file= <>;

#This line will open the input file
open(FILE, "$file");

#This line will open the output file
open(OUT, ">Blust_seq_result.txt");

#This line will create the loop to search the substring
while($file = <FILE>)
{
#This line will search ">gnl"
if($file =~ /^>gnl/)
{
#This line will print all lines containing the character ">gnl" at the beginning
print(OUT "\n$file\n");
}

#This line will search the substring "Query:"
if($file =~ /Query:/)
{

#This line will print all lines containing the substring "Query:"
print(OUT "$file");`enter code here`

}

}
```

How can I get that output?

Comment: `print /\s(\S+)/` would suffice. Stricter matching can be applied, but you didn't really supply enough information.

Comment: Please add more information. I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking.

Comment: This is one of the few times I've seen where comments actually make a program harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Entry your BLAST file name \n";
chomp(my $file= <>);

open my $INFILE, "<", "$file";
open my $OUTFILE, ">", "Blust_seq_result.txt";

while (my $line = <$INFILE>) {
    if ($line =~ /^>gnl/) {
        print $OUTFILE "\n$line\n";
    }
    if ($line =~ /^Query:/) {
        print $OUTFILE $line =~ /\s+(\S+)\s+\S+$/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JS. It works! Can you recommend me some online resources where i can learn Perl good?

Comment: @SSh Perl documentation would be the best place plus a book like Learning Perl should help too. Online I found http://www.sthomas.net/roberts-perl-tutorial.htm#1-Introduction useful though it hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: I have tried to run this on MAC OS X but it isn't working. It worked in windows though.

Comment: Make sure you convert the files to unix formatting. Use `dos2unix` utility to covert the line endings of your input file and script.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what to do actually? I am beginner in perl. thank you.

Comment: The files you had on windows has windows formatting which is LF+CR. Those line endings don't work on Unix. On mac do, `tr -d '\r' < inputFile > tmp && mv tmp inputFile` and similarly do that to your perl script that you wrote on windows box. Once this is done, re-run the script on mac.

Comment: on mac I did whatever you told me to do. Like my file name is BLAST.pl and on mac terminal I did tr -d '\r' <BLAST.pl> tmp && mv tmp BLAST.pl but nothing changed. For MAC, I am just getting >gnl portions as output but not showing query sequences. This program works perfectly for windows. please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use awk:

```
awk '/>gnl/{print;next} /^Query/{x=x $3} END{print x}' file
```

Or if you like Perl:

```
perl -lanE 'say if /^>gnl/; $x.=$F[2] if/^Query/; END{say $x}' file
```